# I need to do datetime conversions in MySQL. How do I determine a timezone of a client?

Tags: mysql, datetime, timezone

i'll try to explain my goal, what i'm trying to achieve and why nothing works for me:
i need to store DATETIME in a MYSQL table. The client should be able to retrieve that DATETIME in two ways:

1. if the datetime 2011-07-12 00:00:00 was added by the user1 with time zone UTC+2 and then the user2 whose timeZone is UTC-3 retrieves this value he should get datetime 2011-07-11 19:00:00. The DST is important here.
2. if the datetime 2011-07-12 00:00:00 was added by the user1, user2 gets the exact same date

that’s it i don't need nothing more. but i cannot find the way of how to do it...

what i came up with is to store the date in user1 timezone that lets to not perform any conversions at all if using 2nd method. the problem is with the 1st method. i guess i could use CONVERT_TZ() function, but what should i use as a timezone parameter? that list of timezones in mysql.time_zone_name table is a complete mess in my opinion. is it practical to let the user pick his timezone from this messy list? For example what should i use: Europe/Warshava or Poland? if I live in a city of Klaipeda(Europe, Lithuania) is it obvious that i should pick time zone Europe/Vilnius? Why these names are so complicated? Maybe there are other MySQL tables which use somehow standardized names like UTC+02:00 width DST and without, like in wondows os(sad I have no chance to compare to other os)?  i could of cause use offset of a timezone "+02:00" like documented  but then the DST information is not preserved. or maybe there are ways of determining user timezone automatically?

Hope I made myself clear. Help and any advice is very much appreciated.

[**edited** (reply to *Flimzy*)]

if i always have to convert to users(clients) date i agry that stroing everything In UTC is best approatch. But what if one user enters the DATETIME 2011.11.12 00:00:00 and the other user have to see exact same time and their timezones doesn’t match, what then? So I decided to not convert date at all when storing and store timezone together. That is my problem. How to determine the clients time zone automatically? Or how to make timezone names not so confusing? That setting is very important for my application and because of that I don’t want to let a user configure it, but if there is no way of doing that I want that that timezone list to be as clear possible.

Comment: If it's a web application then you can detect user's timezone and DST using JavaScript. One good approach is here: http://www.onlineaspect.com/2007/06/08/auto-detect-a-time-zone-with-javascript/

Comment: What is the situation where you need to show user A's time input to user B exactly as it was entered?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you deal with multiple timezones, you should *always* convert your times to UTC before insert, then convert to the user's time zone for display when you pull from the database.

Even if none of your users use UTC, storing in UTC simplifies things greatly.

The reasons for the confusing names, as opposed to just "UTC+02:00 with DST" is that DST is defined differently in different regions within the same time area.  Using an example from my part of the world, The U.S. and Mexico are in the same time zones ("U.S. Central"), but have different DST dates.  The U.S. changes about 2 weeks before Mexico does.  so it's not enough to say "I'm in GMT-05 with DST", because that does not convey *which* DST rules apply to me.

There are many places where DST rules are even more complicated than this example. And this complication just goes to further demonstrate that storing everything in UTC makes life much much simpler :)

Comment: Thank you for helping Flimzy. i edited my post and added a reply there, because i couldn't fit in characters here :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [TimeStamp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html)

Timestamps automatically store timezone information too(its built in actually).

Answer (score 0):

i think i'll use this [javascript](http://site.pageloom.com/automatic-timezone-detection-with-javascript) and then according to [Timezone Detection List](https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect/wiki/Detection_List) build my own list with custom timezone names like (UTC +02:00) Helsinki, Kyiv, Riga, Sofia, Tallinn, Vilnius etc. and leave the user ability to change time zone if something went wrong in auto detection process